# HTML5's Speech Recognition API

Tags: javascript, php, html, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use HTML5's Speech Recognition API, but it's not getting the speech that I'm trying to turn into text. Instead of the words I said, it displayed something else. Please take a look at my code:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = false;
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.onresult = function(event) { 
  alert(event);
}

</script>

<input type = "submit" value = "Start Speaking" onclick = "recognition.start()">
```

Alerted results:

```
[object SpeechRecognizationEvent]
```

Expected results:

```
"Hello"
```

^^^That's what I said.

Comment: does that 'something else' give any clue? (what is it). Correct language selected?

Comment: @planetmaker Alerted results: [object SpeechRecognizationEvent]

Comment: use console.log instead of alert, since alert *.toStrings() the event, also [this](http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/) says the SpeechRecognizationEvent should have a `event.results` entry/array with possible texts and confidences

Comment: @birdspider console.log doesn't work either.

Comment: @frosty: I don't have a mic here, can you try this: http://pastebin.com/S79CdFmx and check in devtools for an output (F12 console)

Comment: @birdspider Clicked the first button. It asked if I wanted to allow it mic access. Clicked allow. Red circle pops up in tab title. Says something. Click the second button to end the recording. Nothing outputs.

Comment: @frosty: your mic works right - you checked that with another program ? further in chrome settings, advanced - is there any strange mic setting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a lot about webkitSpeechRecognition that you can read , you get the object for the following reason :

That gives an object that needs to be handled in this way :

```
recognition.onresult = function(event) { 

   for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) { 
       var identificated = event.results[i][0].transcript;//This is what recognizes 
       if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
             console.log("Final sentence is : " + identificated );  
       }else{
           console.log("I understood : " + identificated );  
        }
}
```

1) Look official demo here [Source Code Here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webplatform-samples/tree/master/webspeechdemo)

2) Or read quickly here (Here is what you need ) : [Example of what you need](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webplatform-samples/tree/master/webspeechdemo)

You can test my library, is of Voice Control using webkitSpeechRecognition

[Artyom Voice Recognition - Control](http://github.com/sdkcarlos/artyom.js)